# Prisma not setting a optional foreign key null

Tags: mysql, node.js, prisma

I am trying to update an optional foreign key in prisma to null, but it gives me an error that value null is not expected but the "undefined" can be done as a value. If try from MySQL to set it as null it works.
If I try to set undefined(which I want NULL not undefined), if previously a value was set, if i want to set undefined the value persist)

Vehicle Prisma Schema

```
     model Vehicle {
          id                        String                  @id @default(uuid())
          vehicle_model_category_id String?
          Vehicle_Model_Category    Vehicle_Model_Category? @relation(fields: [vehicle_model_category_id], references: [id], onUpdate: Cascade, onDelete: Cascade)
     }
     
  model Vehicle_Model_Category {
  id                      String               @id @default(uuid())
  name                    String               @db.VarChar(255)
 ....
  Vehicle                 Vehicle[]
}
```

Here one vehicle model might not have a category model, and normally can be null because also is optional in the schema.
Relationship between Vehicle_Model_Category(1) -> Vehicle_Model(Many)

```
  const vehicle = await prisma.vehicle.update({
      where: {
        id,
      },

      data:{
      Vehicle_Model_Category: null,
      }
 });
```

Error that I get is:

Argument Vehicle_Model_Category for data.Vehicle_Model_Category must not be null. Please use undefined instead.

I try manually to do it on MySQL to update on Mysql, it works but from prisma does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example of how you can update the `Vehicle_Model_Category` field to null using the undefined value (You'll have to temporarily disable the foreign key relationship):

```js
const vehicle = await prisma.vehicle.update({
  where: {
    id,
  },
  data: {
    Vehicle_Model_Category: {
      disconnect: true,
    },
  },
});
```

Also, regarding the Null and Undefined shenanigans, and Prisma is an ORM (JavaScript), and here Undefined is a datatype and conversions can be tricky and often evaluated by case-by-case basis, like here. Here's an official source for it — [**Null and Undefined - Prisma Docs**](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/null-and-undefined).

Answer (score -1):

Prisma differentiates between null and undefined. `null` is a value while `undefined` means do nothing. See this [section](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/null-and-undefined#:%7E:text=Prisma%20Client%20differentiates%20between%20null,undefined%20means%20do%20nothing) of the documentation. Setting a field value to `undefined` is the same as not including the field in the update query at all. From the error message, prisma is expecting you to set it to `undefined` instead of null.

For example, say we have this schema where a User has many posts but a Post may or may not have a user associated with it. Notice the optional relation `author` and the relation scalar `authorId`

```
model User {
  id    Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  posts Post[]
}

model Post {
  id       Int   @id @default(autoincrement())
  author   User? @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId Int?
}
```

If we write a script to create a new post and set the optional relation `author` to null like below

```js
const post = await prisma.post.create({
    data: {
      author: null
    }
  })
```

We'll get an error message `Argument author for data.author must not be null. Please use undefined instead.` which is similar to the error message you have.

I'll update the script to set `author` relation field to `undefined`

```js
const post = await prisma.post.create({
    data: {
      author: undefined
    }
  })
```

We'll get this output

```js
{ id: 2, authorId: null }
```

Comment: But I want to make it null in the database, how can I force to leave it null.

Comment: Please take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but when i set undefined, the same value persist in database, it is not null anymore, but for example if i had before a foreign key, if i set to undefined it stick like that.